# Do we need "at" before "around 7AM" as in "I go to work (at) around 7 AM"? Confusing!

Tags: word-usage

Do we need "at" before "around 7 AM" as in  "I go to work (at) around 7 AM"?

We got these examples in [this dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/around)

> around /əˈraʊnd/  adverb
>
> We got home **at around** 8 o'clock. = (US) We got home **around
>   about** 8 o'clock. [=it was approximately 8 o'clock when we got home]

We also got these examples in [this dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/about_1?q=about)

> He arrived **(at) about** ten.

I don't understand why they use "around" & "about" together. So they use 2 adverbs "around" & "about",  which have same meaning, next to each other

Answer (score 1):

Question:

> Do we need “at” before “around 7AM” as in “I go to work (at) around 7 AM”?

Answer:

> No

You could say:

> I go to work at 7 AM
>   I go to work around 7 AM
>   I go to work at around 7 AM

"Around" means "approximately". However, you could not say "I go to work approximately 7 AM"

> I don't understand why they use "around" & "about" together.

Those words both mean the same thing, and so are redundant. Specifically "around about" has a slow, relaxed, southern feel to it. "Round about 7pm"